# GhostScript auto pagenumbering

Tags: ghostscript, page-numbering

I want to export one certain page from a pdf document to an image and automatically fill the page number in the file name. When I run the following code:

```bsh
gs \                                             
-sDEVICE=jpeg \
-o outfile-%03.jpeg \
-dFirstPage=12 \
-dLastPage=12 \
wo.pdf
```

I get: `outfile-001.jpeg` instead of `outfile-012.jpeg`.

Comment: Ghostscript always numbers its output files from 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote a bash script for the job:

```bsh
function extract_nth_page(){
    printf -v j "outfile-%05g.png" $1
    echo $j
    gs -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -dFirstPage=$1 -dLastPage=$1 -sOutputFile=$j $2 -c quit
    return 0
}

# Extracts page number 42 from myFile.pdf to outfile-00042.png
extract_nth_page 42 myFile.pdf
```